# Boundary of inverse image.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is it necessarily true that given a continuous function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and any set $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, if $x\in \partial(f^{-1}(B))$ then $f(x)\in B$? My answer is that if $B$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is open and so $\partial(f^{-1}(B)) \cap f^{-1}(B) = \emptyset$, so if $x \in \partial(f^{-1}(B))$ then necesarilly $x\notin f^{-1}(B)$ which gives $f(x)\notin B$. Is this reasoning correct?

The problem I was working on is as follows:
A function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous if and only if $\partial(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq f^{-1}(\partial B)$. The first direction ($\Rightarrow$) is where I encountered problems since I used the above assumption.

Comment: I think you have forgotten to say that the conclusion of your reasoning is that the claim is false.  A specific counter-example, like $n = m = 1$, $f(x) = x$ and $B = (0, 1)$ will suffice to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm addressing the question:

> Is it necessarily true that given a continuous function $f\colon
>  \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and any set $B\subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}^m$, if $x\in \partial(f^{-1}(B))$ then $f(x)\in B$?

Consider $n = m = 1$, $f(x) = x$, and $B = \{x \mid 0 < x < 1 \}$.

Then $f^{-1}(B) = B$, and $1$ is in the boundary of this set, but $f(1)$ is not in $B$.

So your reasoning must be incorrect, because the conclusion you're trying to draw is false.

**Pro tip**: When something's hard to prove, look at easy cases to see whether it might just be false. Sometimes it's not, but it never hurts to check a few examples. Doing so might give you insight into proving the thing, too.